# Propositional calculus - I can't get why the answer for this test question is what it is

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Consider the following premises.

1. If A = B then B = C.
2. B != C.
3. If C > D then D < E.
4. F != G and A = B.
5. A = B or C > D.

Alternatives:

a) F != G

b) F != G and D < E

c) A = B

d) B = C or D < E

e) D < E

The answer sheet says the correct alternative is B.

I am confused, because (1) and (2) seems to imply that A != B. In which case (4) would be contradictory. That's why I am wondering if the question itself is wrong.

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting numbers and equations.

Comment: What is the ***question*** which one of the five alternatives is supposed to answer? Is the question perhaps "which of the alternatives is a consequence of the given premises"? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that there is a typo on your source's part, namely being that (4) should be a disjunction.

Making this correction, we have

(6) $A\neq B$. Take the contrapositive of (1) and applying modus ponens with (2).

(7) $C>D$. Use disjunctive syllogism on (5) with (6).

(8) $D<E$. Apply modus ponens on (3) with (7).

(9) $F\neq G$. Apply disjunctive syllogism on (modified 4) with (6).

(10) b) Conjunction between (8) and (9).

Thus b) would then indeed be a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right; the question is wrong. From (4) we get A = B, and then by (1) we get B = C, contradicting (2).

Answer (score -1):

(1) and (2) do not imply that A != B. Indeed is an if, so that IF  A = B, then we have that A = B = C. However in 2, it is not stated that A=B, we only know that B != C,which implies that A != B.

To prove the equality we see that:
 from 4) F!=G and A=B, which implies 5) A=B or C > D.
Hence from 3) we get the answer b!

Notice that the passage from 5 to 3 works as 'or' works when one of the propositions or both are true, so we can take  C > D to be true.

Comment: However, (1) and (2) imply $A \neq B$ by [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens). Why does modus tollens not work here?

Comment: I don't think you should see it that way. I think you should take one of them to be true and then see which one they imply, I think.. but I'm not sure, it's not explicit in the question

Comment: It says "Consider the following premises" meaning that all of those statements are premises, so we need to simplify them down to one equivalent premise by taking them all as true.

Comment: But the premises are contradictory.  B != C is a given and A=B is a given, so 1) => B = C which is a contradiction.

Comment: but 1) doesn't imply A=B. 1) implies that if A = B  is true, then the rest follows. For that implication to be true it could be that A = B or it could be A != B or B = C

Comment: I tend to agree with @fleablood that we have a contradiction within the premises.

Comment: I think that a if-statement and an only-if statement are some 'tools', that you can apply. Knowing that the tool is correct doesn't necessarily means that you are using it in one way (A=B) or another (A != B )